# After first click success, jQuery do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a small demo on paging, but after selecting the first page, it does not work anymore. Please give me a solution. Thanks !!

Code in Index.cshtml

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('ul.pagination li').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var index = $(this).first().text();
        $('#divData').load("/Paging/Table?pageIndex=" + index);
    });
</script>
```

```html
<h2>Index</h2>
<div id="divData">
    @Html.Action("Table");
</div>
```

Code in Table.cshtml

```html
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model[0])
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ID</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Note</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<ul class="pagination">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= Model[1]; i++)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@i</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: instead of `$('ul.pagination li').click(function () {` try delegated event handler ... `$(document).on('click', 'ul.pagination li', function () {` - because it looks like you're overwriting the pagination elements on each `.load` - therefore, losing the click handler

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Great solution. Thank you very much !!